# Image validation in Codigniter Rest api

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using rest api in codeigniter
And in config/form-validation.php file,there is all validations info,this is my code

```
$config = array(
    'usersignup' => array(
        array('field' => 'first_name', 'label' => 'First Name', 'rules' => 'trim|required'),
        array('field' => 'last_name', 'label' => 'Last Name', 'rules' => 'trim|required'),
        array('field' => 'username', 'label' => 'Username', 'rules' => 'trim|required'),
        array('field' => 'password', 'label' => 'Password', 'rules' => 'trim|required'),
        array('field' => 'user_type', 'label' => 'User Type', 'rules' => 'trim|required'),      
        ),  
    )
```

How can i validate image ?

Comment: Have you tried something for it?

Comment: you have to use `upload` library and it has some configuration for that. for example you can use it to upload (use ajax) and return the value of uploaded data to your validation form use `callback_uploadImage` as rule

Answer (score 0):

Actually that depends what you actually wants to validate while upload the image. If just want to check if an image is selected or not you can do that by this way

```
if(isset($_FILES["fileToUpload"])) {
    // Image is selected 
}
```

If you also want to check mime type then do this,

```
if(isset($_FILES["fileToUpload"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";

    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should see an upload form. Try uploading an image file (either a jpg, gif, or png). If the path in your controller is correct it should work.

```
<?php

class Upload extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct()
        {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        }

        public function index()
        {
                $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ' ' ));
        }

        public function do_upload()
        {
                $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
                $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
                $config['max_size']             = 100;
                $config['max_width']            = 1024;
                $config['max_height']           = 768;

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
                {
                        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
                }
                else
                {
                        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

                        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
                }
        }
}
?>
```

You’ll need a destination directory for your uploaded images. Create a directory at the root of your CodeIgniter installation called uploads and set its file permissions to 777.

For more information regarding file upload refer the link https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html#preferences